# Cannot find module '@app/common' error when e2e testing

Tags: testing, jestjs, nestjs

I have microservoce app in `NestJS`

now I'am going to write some e2e test using `Jest` and `supertest`

this is simplified structure of app folders .

there is a common `lib` that contain common module that can be used in every service .

[image]

```js
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppModule } from '../src/app.module';

describe('User Controller', () => {
    let app: INestApplication;

    beforeAll(async () => {
        const moduleRef: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            imports: [AppModule]
        })
            .compile()
        app = moduleRef.createNestApplication();
        await app.init();
    });
});
```

when I try to create my app , I see an error like this

Cannot find module '@app/common' from '../src/infrastructure/data-source/user.data-source.ts'

it seems that it cant find modules in `lib`

Comment: did you know that **jest** won't understand the `@app/` alias unless a proper configuration? see https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/lmnsdtce3y-import-absolute-paths-in-typescript-jest-tests

Comment: @MicaelLevi I've configurated jest.json module name mapper like this :
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "@app/(.*)": "<rootDir>/libs/$1"
 },

but it doesn't

Answer (score 2):

From [ts-jest docs](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/paths-mapping), you'll need to switch from json to javascript (or
typescript) file.

```js
// jest.config.js
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest');

const tsconfig = require('./tsconfig.json');

module.exports = {
  roots: ['<rootDir>'],
  modulePaths: [compilerOptions.baseUrl],
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(tsconfig.compilerOptions.paths),
};
```