# Nest.js error in tests with DI between modules. Cannot find module 'src/foo/foo.module' from 'bar/bar.service.spec.ts'

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, nestjs

Getting error `Cannot find module 'src/foo/foo.module' from 'bar/bar.service.spec.ts'` in a test that depends on a service exported by another module.

I can reproduce this issue by having 2 separate modules in a Nest.js project, say FooModule and BarModule, both exporting their own service, say FooService and BarService, and one of them injecting the other service as a constructor dependency. I haven't found the right approach to set up the test for this scenartio without stepping into above error. Here is a sample of the spec file for the service that has Dependency injection:

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { FooModule } from 'src/foo/foo.module';
import { FooService } from 'src/foo/foo.service';
import { BarService } from './bar.service';

describe('BarService', () => {
  let service: BarService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [BarService, {
        provide: FooService,
        useValue: {test:() => 'This is a test'}
      }],
      imports: [FooModule]
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<BarService>(BarService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Here is how I export the dependency, FooService, in foo.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FooService } from './foo.service';

@Module({
  providers: [FooService],
  exports: [FooService],
})
export class FooModule {}
```

Imports I'm sure they are correct, so can't find any reason for this error.
I want to test the service successfuly despite it has dependencies on another modules. The project runs fine otherwise, so it is just the unit tests.
Appreciate any inputs!

UPDATE: this only happend when running jest.

Comment: Fixed, had to replace ALL occurrences of absolute imports and use relative imports. Not sure I understand why.

Comment: Node doesn't respect or even understand base URLs and I suspect your test framework is running directly under node. This is certainly possible to get to work but it depends on many aspects of your tool chain, but the short of it is that node.js does not allow you to use non-relative paths when referencing between your source code files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find module '@app/common' error when e2e testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76280561/cannot-find-module-app-common-error-when-e2e-testing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this doesn't happen when running the app, only when running jest, right? then is not a nestjs issue but a **jest issue**

jest doesn't understand absolute paths by default, that's why.

follow this another post with the same question: [Cannot find module '@app/common' error when e2e testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76280561)

Comment: Right, forgot to clarify. Thanks.